# How to refer to redis' nil in conditionals?

Tags: redis, rust, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write an if statement in Rust that succeeds in its conditional as long as the result of a get is not `nil`. Like so:

```rust
if database::get(variable) != /* nil */ {}
```

What do I pass in for `nil`?

Comment: could you help me with this problem, I tried but did not fix the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732292/response-type-not-string-compatible-response-was-nil-when-query-redis @CrimsonTide0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to an `Option`? You can simply write `database::get(variable).is_some()` or `.is_none()`.

However, in the more likely scenario where you want to use the value in the variable:

```rust
if let Some(variable_unwrapped) = database::get(variable) {
    // Now you can use the `variable_unwrapped` variable
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If your problem is fully solved, remember to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I tried this way but did not work in this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732292/response-type-not-string-compatible-response-was-nil-when-query-redis what should I do? @Coder-256

Comment: @Dolphin I would suggest you read the chapters in the Rust book about [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#the-option-enum-and-its-advantages-over-null-values) and [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#handling-potential-failure-with-the-result-type). Then, note that the `unwrap()` method for `Option`/`Result` simply tries to match the `Some(T)`/`Ok(T)` variants (respectively) or else panics, and `expect()` does the same thing but with a custom error message.

Comment: The most important takeaway is that in Rust, there is no "nil". Nothing is nullable, unlike languages like Java where *every* reference is nullable by default. Instead, you can use `Option<T>`, which is an enum that either stores `Some(T)` or `None`. Again, the section in the Rust book about `Option` explains it well conceptually, and there is more detailed documentation in the [`std::option` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/index.html).