# how to log failed error entity when delete redis key in rust

Tags: rust

I am using this code to delete redis key in redis:

```
let del_result = del_redis_key(&del_key).await;
    match del_result {
        Ok(success) => {
            info!("increment delete success...")
        }
        Err(failed) => {
            let failed_data = serde_json::to_string(&failed.as_result()).unwrap();
            info!("increment delete failed...,{}",failed_data);
        }
    };
```

when delete redis key failed, I want to log out the error message, but when I tried to log error(`log = "0.4"`), shows error when compile:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `as_result` found for enum `mobc_error::Error` in the current scope
  --> src/biz/music/songs_controller.rs:66:61
   |
66 |             let failed_data = serde_json::to_string(&failed.as_result()).unwrap();
   |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `mobc_error::Error`
   |
```

what should I do to logout the error information?BTW, this is the delete redis key function looks like:

```
pub async fn del_redis_key(key: &str,) -> Result<()> {
    let config_redis_string = getConfig("redisConnectionStr");
    let REDIS_CON_STRING: &str = config_redis_string.as_str();
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open(REDIS_CON_STRING).expect("can create redis client");
    let mut redis_conn = get_con(redis_client);
    let mut redis_conn_unwrap = redis_conn.unwrap();
    let del_result = redis_conn_unwrap.del(key).map_err(RedisCMDError)?;
    FromRedisValue::from_redis_value(&del_result).map_err(|e| RedisTypeError(e).into())
}
```

Comment: What is the type the `Err` variant? It would seem that the type does not have the method `as_result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Error` enum in your another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732292/response-type-not-string-compatible-response-was-nil-when-query-redis) is how `mobc_error::Error` is defined, it doesn't look to have the method `as_result` like @Kendas pointed out.

However, I notice every variant of the enum is annotated with [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/1.0.30/thiserror/)'s #[error("...")] message. That means thiserror has generated the Display implementation for the enum and the error message associated with a concrete variant can be displayed. If that's the case, I think you can simplify the code the following way. Give it a try.

```
Err(failed) => {
    info!("increment delete failed...,{}", failed);
}
```